# Issue in creating new maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm new to maven and behind the office proxy

steps followed :
 installed the maven plugin for eclipse 
installed the spring plugin

New project-> maven

error

> Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-bundle-archetype:pom:1.0.2 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-bundle-archetype:pom:1.0.2
>   from/to central (http:repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to
>   http:repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/osgi/spring-osgi-bundle-archetype/1.0.2/spring-osgi-bundle-archetype-1.0.2.pom

Tried the following changing the window-> preference-> maven -> 
archytypes 
to

```
http:repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

also by pointing to the `settings.xml` file

Would appreciate it if anybody could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You're having problems downloading the archetype, likely due to firewall.

On the first screen of New Maven Project wizard, check the  "Create a Simple Project (skip archetype selection)" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Have you told Eclipse to go through the proxy?
Go to Window -> preferences then General -> Network Connections. There you can properly set the proxy. Restart Eclipse before trying again.
Also be sure that the Maven plugin is configured correctly in Window -> preferences -> Maven -> User Setting: the 'Global settings' textbox should not be empty.